# Какой тип сказуемого?

Tags: синтаксис, тип-сказуемого

> Он мечтает стать актером.

*Мечтает* -- модальное слово, *стать* -- полуотвлеченная связка, *актером* -- именная часть -- следовательно, сложное именное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, осложненное именное сказуемое, оно образуется за счет увеличения числа элементов вспомогательной части.